# mysql-workbench-community wont run

Tags: mysql-workbench

it seems that other possibilities than snap don't exist any longer.

The Oracle version produces other errors.

So i did:

snap install mysql-workbench-community

When i run it i get:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/0’: Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/mysql-workbench-community/7/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications.gschema.xml': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/mysql-workbench-community/7/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.a11y.gschema.xml': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/mysql-workbench-community/7/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard.gschema.xml': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/mysql-workbench-community/7/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier.gschema.xml': File exists
...
(mysql-workbench-bin:932077): Gtk-WARNING **: 07:46:26.995: cannot open display: localhost:12.0
```

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Somebody running mysql-workbench without these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to install a snap as `root`. Don't do that. Snaps are installed under a typical user account.

0. Open Terminal (if not already open)
1. Install the snap:

   ```
   $ snap install mysql-workbench-community
   ```
2. Let it install, then output this message:

   ```
   mysql-workbench-community 8.0.22 from Tonin Bolzan (tonybolzan) installed
   ```
3. Confirm it's available to run:

   [image: MySQL Workbench]
4. Start the snap:

   [image: MySQL Workbench Open]

   ***Note:** Starting seems to be painfully slow (~30 seconds).*

I just went through all the steps to confirm the snap was still available and operational. Currently running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on the machine that did the work

Comment: snap install mysql-workbench-community
error: access denied (try with sudo)

Comment: Before i did a snap remove mysql-workbench-community

Comment: Your hints are very welcome but i am using the server version of Ubuntu without GUI

Comment: Specificity is incredibly important when you're using a server *and* when you're asking random people on the Internet for assistance. MySQL Workbench is a client-side application, not something that runs on the server itself.

Comment: I tried on a different VM -> install with sudo, execute as normal user -> success

Comment: I tried again this way on the original VM -> cannot open display -> something wrong with GTK MoTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol

(mysql-workbench-bin:1056009): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:02:10.949: cannot open display: localhost:12.0

Comment: Apps like xload run without problems